# Codeigniter 403 Error on Live Login

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-403

I have a live site [link to site](http://jksmacedonia.com) that I'm currently developing. I am using codeigniter for the setup and bootstrap for the UI.

**The backstory -**
site has a live login and when you enter correct username/password, it would redirect you to the admin page. All of this was working until last weekend when I was upgrading some features and somewhere along the line the site started throwing 403 errors. After you'd log in, you get the 403 error and afterwards you couldn't visit any of the pages on the domain because all of them throws the 403 error.

I looked at almost every article here about codeigniter and 403 errors and thought the reason was me missing semicolons within the href or src attributes. Like this `<a href="<?php echo base_url()."controller/function".$bla."" ?>"` but this changed nothing when I changed it (not sure if this did anything or not). I also looked online, but didn't find much.

I don't know what the problem is. I quadruple checked the codes that are somehow connected to the login but neither I nor [phpcodechecker](https://phpcodechecker.com/) didn't find anything wrong with my code, and usually the code checker solves most of the things I miss.

Since the login is where the problem occurs, here is the codes to the controllers, views and models used for the login and afterwards.

**Login view**

```
<br>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4 offset-4">

<div class="login-form">
        <?php echo validation_errors();?>

        <?php echo form_open('admin/magacinLogin');?>


        <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>       

        <div class="form-group">

            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">

            <label class="pull-left checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="rem" id="rem"> Remember me</label>

        </div>        

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller login**

```
public function magacinLogin()

    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|callback_check_db'); 



        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 

        {   

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);

            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

            redirect('/admin_page');

        }

        else

        {

            $this->load->view('header_en');
            $this->load->view('logo');
            $this->load->view('navbar');
            $this->load->view('mlogin');
            $this->load->view('footer');

        }

    }



    function check_db()

    {

        extract($_POST);

        $try_login = $this->admin_model->login($username, $password);



        if(!$try_login)

        {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_db', 'Wrong username or password');

            return FALSE;

        }

        else

        {

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);

            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

            redirect('/admin_page');
        }



    }
```

**Model for login checkup**

```
function login($username, $password)

        {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE xxxx ='".$username."'";

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);            

            $hash = $this->db->query($sql)->row()->xxxx;





            if ($query->num_rows() == 1 && password_verify($password, $hash)) {

                return $query->result_array();

            }

            else

            {

                return false;

            }

        }
```

**After logging in, different controller**

```
function index()

 {

   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))

   {

     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];


     $this->load->view('header_magacin');

     $this->load->view('test');

     $this->load->view('footer_magacin');

   }

   else

   {

     //If no session, redirect to login page

     redirect('/login', 'refresh');

   }

 }
```

Thank you for reading and I hope you can share some knowledge with me.

EDIT:

I want to add that site is hosted on a litespeed web server. On the 403 error on the bottom says this page is hosted by litespeed web server. I was reading about the lite web server & also asked my hosting provider about any changes. So far they haven't written back so I don't know yet.

Comment: Remove / from all of redirect like this. `redirect('login', 'refresh')`

Comment: I removed all of / from my script, but the error persists.

Comment: Change your php version as first. Use different version of php to solve your problem maybe your upgrade make this problem.

Comment: That's unlikely, since this page worked as I wanted a week ago. The php version is 5.6. I haven't upgraded the php